# Mapbox iOS SDK 2 - Detect click on polygon

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I need to recognize which MGLPolygon was selected by user on Mapbox 2.0 map.

```
- (void)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotation:(id <MGLAnnotation>)annotation
```

doesn't work.

How can I customize MGLPolygon to make it clickable?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality isn't supported yet: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2082

Comment: thank you for reply. Is it scheduled to be released soon? Should I wait or I should start looking for another solution?